# Joomla: Passing a variable into getInput()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

I'm building a backend component (1.6 / 1.7 / 2.5) where I need to pass a variable from another view into a field in a new record.  Variable passing is working fine.

My problem is using getInput().

To start with different doc pages have different amounts and formatting of parameters - confusing!  For example:

http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JForm/getInput: `getInput($name, $group= '_default', $formControl= '_default', $groupControl= '_default', $value=null)`

vs

http://docs.joomla.org/JForm::getInput/1.6:

```
public function getInput (
    $name 
    $group=null 
    $value=null
)
```

---

**The problem:**

I just need to pass a variable as a default value, something like:

`echo $this->form->getInput('id', $value=$this->userID );?>`

The above code makes the input field disappear.  If I take out the `$value=$this->userID` the input field shows up though obviously doesn't have any default value.  I've also tried:

```
$value=$this->userID;
echo $this->form->getInput('id', $value );
```

And same problem, the input field goes away.  I tried a few other variations but basically if I try to put anything else within getInput() it doesn't work nor can I find any good working examples of how to use these other parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the source](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/development/tags/1.6.x/1.6.3/libraries/joomla/form/form.php&view=markup), this is the correct API:

```
getInput($name, $group = null, $value = null)
```

And `getInput()` just calls `getField()`:

```
getField($name, $group = null, $value = null)
```

Which means you should be doing this to set a default value:

```
echo $this->form->getInput('id', null, $this->userID ); // Returns the $field->input String
```

Or:

```
$field = $this->form->getField('id', null, $this->userID ); // Returns the JFormField object
```

Comment: Thank you!!  That was an excellent explanation too on how to approach that, all of this is pretty new to me.